# Subprocess to execute commands on Windows machine

Tags: python, subprocess, wmi, pywin32

I am trying to connect to remote Windows machine and from commandline execute few commands. Commands are like: I have executable in a certain folder, go to that folder and run the command

`InstallUtil.exe <exe_name>`

Here is my code:

```
  class WindowsMachine:
def __init__(self, hostname, username, password):
    self.hostname = hostname
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
    # self.remote_path = hostname
    try:
        print("Establishing connection to .....%s" %self.hostname)
        connection = wmi.WMI(self.hostname, user=self.username, password=self.password)
        print("Connection established")

        try:

            print(os.listdir(r"C:\Program Files\BISYS\BCE"))

            a = subprocess.check_output(["InstallUtil.exe","IamHere.exe"], cwd="C:/Program Files/ABC/BCD/",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            print(a)


        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))


    except wmi.x_wmi:
        print("Could not connect to machine")
        raise

w = WindowsMachine(hostname,username,password)
print(w)
print(w.run_remote())
```

But I am getting error saying:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: this error message happens because `InstallUtil.exe` isn't found. Are you sure you can run this from the command line?

Comment: Yes. I went to that directory and executed the command:  `InstallUtil.exe <exename>.exe` and It worked.. I also tried `installutll  <exename>.exe`

Comment: you probably need to change your current directory the time the command executes. maybe you should try `subprocess.check_output(["InstallUtil.exe"," IamHere.exe"],cwd="C:/Program Files/ABC/BCD",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: If I give the command on commandline `installutill C:/Program Files/ABC/DEF/Iamhere.exe` it works but not from my script

Comment: error is: `WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid`

Comment: where is installutil located? copying/pasting the command in a cmd works?

Comment: installutil is locate din the same folder where executable is. And If i run it from commandline then it works.   `InstallUtil.exe <exename>.exe` and It worked.. I also tried` installutll <exename>.exe `

Comment: I don't understand: you're trying to run this command remotely? but the connection to wmi is lost as soon as you exit the `__init__` method. moreover you've posted 2 different WindowsError messages. Which one is it? oh I understand: you have updated your code with my suggestion. So it means that the directory you've passed doesn't exist.

Comment: Directory exists, it is there

Comment: ok, it seems that you changed the directory name for the question. Can you post the exact command you're using?

Comment: I am using following command on commandline:
`Installutil.exe "C:\Program Files\ABC\BCD\Iamhere.exe"`

Comment: and the python counterpart?

Comment: Here is the python part:
 `a = subprocess.check_output(["InstallUtil.exe","IamHere.exe"], cwd="C:/Program Files/ABC/BCD/",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: that should work. Can you try `os.listdir("C:/Program Files/ABC/BCD/")` ?

Comment: I used the exact command and pasted in my python code as :
`import os
print(os.listdir("C:/Program Files/ABC/BCD/"))`  gives an error `WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: C:/Program Files/ABC/BCD/*.*`

Comment: that is because this directory does _not_ exist! and that's the source of your problems. Can you create a standalone python code just with those 2 lines (in case the wmi stuff is a problem)?

Comment: directory is there. I check it

Comment: ok, then copy/paste the path from windows explorer in the python script. Some space chars are different/altered when e-mailed for instance, you may have an hidden/wrong char in your path (use the `r` prefix to be able to use backslashes safely: `r"C:\Program Files\...`

Comment: when I prefixed with r outside the () path, it is giving error:  `    ```print(os.listdir(r"C:\Program Files\BISYS\BCE\"))
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal```  Do I need to add any library or I am missing something

Comment: OK don't put the last antislash. Paste it from windows explorer to be sure it's valid.

Comment: Here it is:  
```print(os.listdir(r"C:\Program Files\ABC\BCD"))``` \P is in purple color, \B both are in Red/Dark pink color. 
giving error: 

` WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files\\ABC\\BCD/*.*`

Comment: I'm sorry, but the directory just doesn't exist on your system...

Comment: It is there I checked, I called help and got confirmed that it exists.

Comment: you mean on the remote machine, right?

Comment: yes, on remote machine. I have access from my local machine and I am admin on both

Comment: I understand: the main issue is to run a remote command in python. It seems that just invoking wmic doesn't work here. Check the answer below (not sure it solves it), or use "psexec" from sysinternals to bypass all that (runs a process on a remote host)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, if your goal is to run process on the remote Windows machine first of all you should keep your remote connection open, so instead of storing it in local variable `connection` store it in class member `self.connection`.
Now, to execute command on the remote machine using WMI, you should do something like [this(WMI tutorial)](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html#creating-wmi-objects):

```
class ConnectToRemoteWindowsMachine:
      def __init__(self, hostname, username, password):
          self.hostname = hostname
          self.username = username
          self.password = password
          # self.remote_path = hostname
          try:
              print("Establishing connection to .....%s" %self.hostname)
              self.connection = wmi.WMI(self.hostname, user=self.username, password=self.password)
              print("Connection established")
          except wmi.x_wmi:
              print("Could not connect to machine")
              raise

      def run_remote(self, async=False, minimized=True):

          SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1

          process_startup = self.connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
          process_startup.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL

          process_id, result = c.Win32_Process.Create(
              CommandLine="notepad.exe",
              ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup
          )
          if result == 0:
              print "Process started successfully: %d" % process_id
          else:
              raise RuntimeError, "Problem creating process: %d" % result


w = ConnectToRemoteWindowsMachine(hostname,username,password)
print(w)
print(w.run_remote())
```

Comment: Does it work? Does it print process_id or does it print error message?

Comment: Yes, it prints process id and return value as 0

Comment: afaik it is not possible with WMI